# group by multiple columns (Dynamically) of datatable by linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

i want to group by multiple columns in a datatable by linq query.

i tried like this,

```
var _result = from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()

group row by new
{
    id=row.Field<object>(_strMapColumn),
    value=row.Field<object>(_strValueColumn),
} into g
select new
{
    _strMapColumn = g.Key.id,
    ToolTip = g.Sum(r => grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Double>(__strToolTip[1]))),
};
```

its works fine. my question is i have 10 column names in a strToolTip array i want to access 10 column names dynamically like for loop is it possible?

i want like this

```
select new
{_strMapColumn = g.Key.id,

   for(int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
   {    
       ToolTip+index = g.Sum(r => getDoubleValue(r.Field<Double>(__strToolTip[1])))
   }   
};
```

and also want to add a DataType Dynamically please kindly provide the answer for solve this.
linq query is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by a Dictionary and pass a custom comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, object>> {
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, object> a, Dictionary<string, object> b) {
        if (a == b) { return true; }
        if (a == null || b == null || a.Count != b.Count) { return false; }
        return !a.Except(b).Any();
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> columnsToGroupBy = ...
var rows = tbl.AsEnumerable();
var grouped = rows.GroupBy(r => columnsToGroupBy.ToDictionary(c => c, c => r[c]), new MyComparer());
var result = grouped.Select(g => {
    // whatever logic you want with each grouping
    var id = g.Key["id"];
    var sum = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("someCol"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ChaseMedallion, I got dynamic grouping working. 
Equals method was not enough, I had to add `GetHashCode` to `MyComparer` as well:

```
public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, object> a)
{
    return a.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
}
```